# Is there an IDE for Fortran that can check values of variables?

Tags: fortran, ide

I used to use Matlab and one feature I relied on was that it allowed you to check the value of all variables easily. For example, if I ran a sample program like "a+b=c, c+d=e", it automatically saves the value of c and can be introspected directly.

Now I turn to Fortran. My current IDE just builds the code into an "exe" and I need to save necessary values specifically. If I'm doing a calculation with hundreds of variables it is hard to manage.

So I'm asking is there an IDE allowing me to check values of variables directly without saving each of them manually?

p.s. Is there any term of this feature? Is it called "memory introspection"?

Comment: Welcome to the difference between a compiled and an interpreted language. If you wish to examine the values while the program is running you will either have to write them out, possible to disk, or use a debugger, interrupt the run at the appropriate point, and examine the value directly.

Comment: This is what debuggers are for. Some debuggers are integrated into an IDE (I assume Intel Fortran and similar will have this in the MS Visual Studio on Windows) and there are graphical interfaces to debuggers which look similar to an IDE (nemiver, kgdb, ddd,...)

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I know what to look at!